# Ntds.dit found in another location

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

Just I am trying to understand some AD concepts and when looked to find my AD database file, I couldn't see any folder named "Ntds" inside C:\Windows. Rather I could find the file "Ntds.DIT" inside C:\Windows\System32. I had a check in 2 environments and found the same.

Googled and found [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/91ef5845-e5f7-470e-ae26-a8bb3e69c4f9/2-ntdsdit-files-in-windows-server-2008-r2-and-active-directory-logging?forum=winserverDS) post, but I know by default this database file gets created inside C:\Windows\Ntds\ folder. Then if it has not created such a file, then how AD works properly in those environments? Or is it some information that I am missing related to this?

FYI, Checked Windows 2003 R2 AD servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location of `Ntds.dit` is configurable during the process of promoting a domain controller; it doesn't need to be in the default location.

To determine where the active file is located, check `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NTDS\Parameters`.

Comment: Thanks Shane.. Exactly answered.. You can find those information from the entries "DSA Database file" and "DSA working Directory"..